# SQL join concat on inequality

Tags: sql

I am struggling with query logic. I have two tables, e.g.

Table1:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Table2:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | a |
| 0 | 1 | b |
| 0 | 2 | c |
| 1 | 0 | d |
| 1 | 0 | e |
| 1 | 1 | f |
| 1 | 2 | g |

I need to left-join Table2 on Table1 on Table1.A = Table2.A, Table1.B **>** Table2.B, concatenating the values of C. The result of the above tables would be

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 0 | 2 | a,b |
| 1 | 1 | d,e |
| 1 | 2 | d,e,f |

How can this be accomplished? (Note the inequality condition on column B.) The actual Table1 has around 10k rows, Table2 10M-ish. I want to use SQL queries on Azure Databricks.

Thanks!

EDIT:
OK, never mind. My mistake was to try to do everything in one step. The solution is to join on the equality condition for A, then filter on the inequality condition on B, then concat, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( A int, B int);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (0, 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (0, 2);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 2);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (C int, D int, E varchar(2));
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (0, 0, 'a');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (0, 1, 'b');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (0, 2, 'c');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 0, 'd');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 0, 'e');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 1, 'f');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 2, 'g');

SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, GROUP_CONCAT(Table2.E)
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.A = Table2.C
WHERE Table1.B > Table2.D
GROUP BY Table1.A, Table1.B
```

Comment: Why are you saying you want a left outer join? Looks like a mere inner join to me. And what keeps you from writing the query? You have already shown the join condition, so why not apply this? I don't understand what additional information you want from us.

Comment: How are you getting, for example, 0,2=>a,b? If you join on A and B where A=0 and B=2 then the only value you’d get for C is c

Comment: The difficulty is the inequality in the join condition, Table1.B > Table2.B, I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: You want a join plus  a string aggregation. The last feature is DBMS specific. Tag the question with your DBMS.

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and post it as an answer